# Should I post another answer if it is different from my other one?

Tags: discussion, answers

I've just stumbled upon this situation:

**Background**

I saw a question and posted my answer. It's got some upvotes. Some comments were made on my answer stating that it isn't the best solution (and I agreed). I check and there is indeed a posted answer with a better solution (that has got accepted). I upvoted that better answer.
Now I thought on a slightly better solution, but it is similar to the accepted answer.

**Question**

Should I post another answer, edit my answer and add the other solution or not post the answer at all?

**Edit 1**:
As raised by @Bathsheba, one could say that posting a similar answer is plagiarism. This made me search and as by Merriam-Webster's, it is [plagiarizing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plagiarizing) if:

> - one steal and pass off (the ideas or words of another) as one's own :
>   use (another's production) without crediting the source
> - one commit literary theft :  present as new and original an idea
>   or product derived from an existing source

So by refering to another answer and stating that mine offers an improvement, **would not be plagiarism**.

**Question 2**:
Would the new answer be well-received by the community?

Comment: @ale, indeed the comments on the refered question is almost the same. But I didn't see the case that the new answer is similar to another one from other user.

Answer (score 1):

If your new answer differs from your current one, then you ought to re-answer. If you edit your current answer you discredit any voting on it. If your conscience is telling you that your current answer is misleading and harmful to the credibility of a Q & A site, then you should delete it. (I wish there was a badge - awarded once - for deleting an answer of your own with a certain number of upvotes. That could help folk gauge the credibility of an answerer.)

Stack Exchange works best if there are a selection of answers to choose from. That invariably means that good answers will be similar: indeed on many sites questions that are asked where answers would be substantially different are closed for being too opinion based. Similar answers can nonetheless offer different perspectives, and that can be useful.

Therefore it's not relevant if your new answer is similar to another one.

But do shy away from abject plagiarism though.

Comment: How about if I refer to the answer whose mine is similar and state that it is an improvement of some kind? Is it still risky to be considered plagiarism? No, the answer is not misleading or harmful. It is just a simple solution that covers the question but do not cover **all** possible scenarios on the real-world.

Comment: Only you can be the judge of whether or not you plagiarised your answer from another one.